# This simple algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{cases}
3x + y = \frac{12}{y^2}\\
3y + x = \frac{15}{x^2}
\end{cases}

$x+y = ?$

I tried adding side by side but I found only $4x+4y = \dfrac{15}{x^2} + \dfrac{12}{y^2}$ so I couldn't find anything. Can someone solve it?

Comment: If one edits a question, he should at least fix the tags and give a decent formatting: it does not take much effort. I can't edit it myself, but this should be tagged algebra-precalculus.

Comment: @bharb I'm sorry for missing the tag.  I've [suggested that](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/567937).

Answer (score 8):

1. Multiply the first equation by $y^2$: $3xy^2+y^3 = 12$
2. Multiply the second equation by $x^2$: $3x^2y+x^3=15$
3. Add them up to get $3xy^2+y^3+3x^2y+x^3=(x+y)^3=27.$

Hence, $x+y=3$.

Comment: Nice and clean and you'll deserve an upvote for it but why do you ignore the two complex solutions $\frac{3^{\frac{3}{2}}i-3}{2}$ and $-\frac{3^{\frac{3}{2}}i+3}{2}$? Not in the syllabus at the time they teach pre-calculus?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi Most likely not.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I'm sorry that I missed the complex roots.  When teachers teach quadratic equations (in one variable), they usually reject non-real roots.  Even in math competitions in high schools, from my experience, usually the variables are assumed to be real unless otherwise specified.  Therefore, I overlooked them carelessly.  IMHO, I think (correct me if I'm wrong) finding complex roots is within the scope of the (algebra-precalculus) tag.  By the way, it's me who changed the tag of this question to (algebra-precalculus).

Comment: @GNUSupporter I asked without any ulterior motive, I just wanted to know the reason behind your decision because I don't have much knowledge about the specific syllabi of the different jurisdictions (assuming USA in this specific case but the individual states differ, too, as far as I know), so: no reason for you to apologize.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi It's simple : I want to answer it as quick as possible, and I had never thought of complex roots.